# Limit $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt{\log(x)\log(ax)}-\log(x)=\frac{\log{a}}{2}$

Tags: limits

I feel really dumb asking this, but I am stuck.  Why is

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt{\log(x)\log(ax)}-\log(x)=\frac{\log{a}}{2}$$

(according to Wolfram Mathematica).

Let's assume that $a>1$.  I expand the $\log(ax)$ term and obtain:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt{\log^2(x)+\log(x)\log(a)}-\log(x)$$

The term inside the square root is larger than $\log^2(x)$ due to addition of $\log(x)$ times a constant, and my intuition suggests that the limit diverges. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$

\begin{align}
&\root{\ln\pars{x}\ln\pars{ax}} - \ln\pars{x}
={\ln\pars{x}\ln\pars{ax} - \ln^{2}\pars{x}
  \over \root{\ln\pars{x}\ln\pars{ax}} + \ln\pars{x}}
={\ln\pars{x}\ln\pars{a}
  \over \root{\ln\pars{a}\ln\pars{x} + \ln^{2}\pars{x}} + \ln\pars{x}}
={\ln\pars{a}
  \over \root{\ln\pars{a}/\ln\pars{x} + 1} + 1}
\stackrel{x \to \infty}{\to} \color{#0000ff}{\Large\half\,\ln\pars{a}}
\end{align}

Comment: Hmmm... for some reason this answer didn't appear before others (even though the system states that it was here longer...  either a bug with my browser or math.SE...

Comment: I noticed that. I was the first who tried an answer. Thanks.

Comment: All good answers, and now I actually like your better, as it only uses simple algebra (and makes me feel dumber for not seeing it :) ).  I think it's only right if I accept yours.

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt{\log^2(x)+\log(x)\log(a)}-\log(x) =
\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\log(x)\sqrt{1+\frac{\log(a)}{\log(x)}}-\log(x)\\
=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\log(x)\left[\sqrt{1+\frac{\log(a)}{\log(x)}}-1\right]
= \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} \log(x) \left[{1+\frac{1}{2}\frac{\log(a)}{\log(x)}}-1\right] = \frac{\log a}{2}
$$

Added as a comment:

Finding the limit of $\sqrt{1+\theta}$ as $\theta \to 0$ comes up all the time, so here is a useful trick to use is:
Let
$$f = \sqrt{1+\theta}$$ and
$$g= 1+\frac{\theta}{2}$$
Then
$$
f-g = \frac{f^2-g^2}{f+g} = -\frac{\frac{\theta^2}{4}}{f+g}\to 0 \text{ as } \theta \to 0$$

Comment: Almost identical answers several seconds apart.  Thank you for your answer, and I wish I could accept both of them...  accepting Claude's because he stated the Taylor approximation of the radical, which is what I was missing...

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help. I added a comment that does not require Taylor series and provides explicit formula for the difference.

Comment: Thanks for the formula for the difference.  It nicely matches the order of the Taylor remainder... :)

Answer (score 1):

Take out log(x] from the radical. You then obtain log(x) Sqrt[1 + log(a) / log(x)]. Remember that Sqrt[1+y] is almost (1 + y / 2) when y is small. Since x is large, then log(a) / log(x) is small and consequently the radical can be approximated by log(x) [1 + log(a) / (2 log(x))].
Now, expand and substract log(x). You end with log(a) / 2 for the limit.

Comment: As mentioned in the comment to the other answer, there were two of them several seconds apart.  I can't believe I forgot the approximation of that radical by the Taylor series expansion of $\sqrt{1+x}$ around $x=0$.  That was what I was missing.  Thank you!